# Data grid View header Height is changing at run time how to fix that?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I am Working in ASP VB.net , I have Gridview Bounded With SQL DataSource. I Have to add/delete rows at run time .The Problem Is when there is no Items In grid the header Itself Occupies The Full Height of grid i.e the total height is splited according to number of rows but I need to fix header and row heights ,

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRequestItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     Height="76pt" Width ="871px"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     style="font-size: 14pt;  table-layout :fixed;" 
     CellPadding="1" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="TempID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowPaging="True" >
```

the colums property..

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Sno" HeaderText="Sno"    SortExpression="Sno">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" Height="20px" Width="25px" 
     VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Names="Segoe UI"  HorizontalAlign="Center" 
         Font-Size="14pt" />
```

........

other properties are ..

```
   <EmptyDataRowStyle Height="20pt" VerticalAlign="Top" />
   <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="14pt" Height="20px" 
      VerticalAlign="Top" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <RowStyle Height="20pt" VerticalAlign="Top" Wrap="True" BackColor="#E6F2FF"  
     FontNames="Segoe UI" Font-Size="12pt" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Names="Segoe UI" Font-Size="14pt" />
   </asp:GridView>
```

Can Anybody Help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove *height="76"* from your GridView definition.

Also, consider specifying your styling using CssClass instead of via attributes.   Here is an example of this: http://www.etechpulse.com/2013/08/asp-gridview-css-style-sample-user.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting size of header row using CSS rather than inline styling in Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRequestItems" runat="server" style="font-size:14pt;table-layout :fixed;height:76px;" 
HeaderStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader" 
>  

<style type="text/css">
        .FixedHeader {
            position: absolute;
            font-weight: bold;
        }     
</style>
```

Comment: I Just Romoved the height of grid and its working , thank you for  considering